# Asp Boiler Plate- proxy support for angular

Tags: c#

In Asp Boiler Plate, Currently, only jQuery proxies are generated. Is there any way I can achieve this for Angular proxies?

```
<script src="~/AbpServiceProxies/GetAll?type=Angular" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I tried with *type=angular* in src but does not work. I am going to try nswag to achieve this but not too sure how!

Shows this error:

> Abp.AbpException: Could not find a proxy script generator with given name: angular